# Parse application/ld+json in java/android studio

Tags: java, android, html, json, json-ld

I'm trying to access "datePublished" from [here](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/article/minecraft-java-edition-1-17-1). It is visible in source code as:

```
            <script type="application/ld+json">


{
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "NewsArticle",
    "mainEntityOfPage": {
        "@type": "WebPage",
        "@id": "https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/article/minecraft-java-edition-1-17-1"
    },
    "headline": "Article headline",
    "image": [
        "https://www.minecraft.net/content/dam/games/minecraft/screenshots/1-17-1-release-header.jpg"
    ],
    "datePublished": "2021-07-06T13:42:49.957+0000",
    "author": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "Adrian Östergård"
    },
    "publisher": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "Minecraft",
        "logo": {
            "@type": "ImageObject",
            "url": "https://www.minecraft.net/etc.clientlibs/minecraft/clientlibs/main/resources/img/header/logo.png"
        }
    }
}</script>
```

I've tried using a url to string parser and then extract the json but this element doesn't show up in the log.
Many thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Please show the attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: had Regex enabled on console log so date didn't appear...
Guess who just wasted about 12h of their life :')